# C Program to emulate command line prompt

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to implement a small C program which will execute similarly to Linux shell command prompt `$ sort < Names.txt | uniq | wc - l`. to do this I am using execlp to run the commands

the resulting program will sort the arbitrary list of names and removes the duplicates. It sorts the list because it needs duplicate lines adjacent for them to be removed. Then just counts the number of lines.

Ive posted my code, it currently just gets hung up after I compile `gcc -o sortuniqwc sortuniqwc.c` and run `./sortuniqwc < Names.txt`. if I comment out the pipe of the fd each system call seems to execute properly. I'm not sure why it is not piping the processes to the system calls properly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *arv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd1[2]; //making file descriptor 1

    if (pipe(fd1) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe failed");
        return 1;
    }

    pid = fork(); //first child for sort
    //printf("the pid for pipe parent is %d and the child pid is %d", getppid(), getpid());

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork error");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd1[1], 1);
        close(fd1[0]);
        //printf("the child process running sort is %d\n", getpid());
        execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);
        printf("sort exec - should not be here");
        exit(0);
    }

    wait(0);

    int fd2[2];

    if (pipe(fd2) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe failed");
        return 1;
    }

    pid = fork(); //second child for uniq

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd1[0], 0);
        dup2(fd2[1], 1);
        close(fd1[1]);
        close(fd2[0]);
        //printf("the child process running uniq is %d\n", pid);
        execlp("/usr/bin/uniq", "uniq", NULL);
        printf("uniq exec - you shouldnt be here");
        exit(0);
    }

    wait(0);

    pid = fork(); //3rd child process for wc

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd2[0], 0);
        close(fd2[1]);
        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd1[1]);
        //printf("the child process running wc is %d\n", getpid());
        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
        printf("wc exec - you shouldnt be here\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    //parent

    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd1[1]);
    close(fd2[0]);
    close(fd2[1]);

    wait(NULL);

    printf("CHILD COMPLETE \n");
}
```

Comment: . o O ( how often has the name YaUs (Yet another Un*x shell) been taken this year already? )

Comment: Pipes can only hold so much data before blocking a process.  I think you need to create all the pipes first, all the forks and execs need to be done, also the and then the main program needs to read stdin and pass it down the pipe.  Then when all input processing is done you start closing the pipes and wait for the child processes to quit.

Comment: @Fred The parent doesn't need to read the input and pass it down, the `sort` child can do that... But you're right that it's best for all children to run in parallel instead of waiting for each sequentially. For small inputs though, the problem here is the dangling copy of thr write end of `fd1` in the parent which isn't closed.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - The parent needs to `close()` its copy of the write end of the pipe attached to `sort`'s output. Adding `close(fd1[1])` just before the first wait "fixes" the issue.

The program "hangs" in the second call to `wait()` (which waits for the `uniq` child to exit<sup>1</sup>). However, `uniq` never exits because its standard input, which is connected to the read end of the `fd1` pipe, is never closed. There are two copies of this file descriptor in the system: the first belongs to the child process that `exec`'s `sort`, and this is indeed closed as expected by `sort`. But the other copy belongs to the parent process which doesn't `close()` it. Since there is still at least one open file descriptor for the write end of the pipe, the pipe is not closed.

This solution also requires the *entire* sort output to be buffered in the pipe (i.e., in the kernel). For non-trivial inputs, it would be much better to fork off the children in reverse order, connect up all their pipes, and let them run in parallel. This is closer to what a real, robust shell would do.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Or to receive a signal, etc., which a robust shell should check for.</sup>